# How to set property values in new object from object from List and get a new List of the same objects in which properties are set using java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

For example here is my code :

```
   List<EmployeeDto> employees = new ArrayList<>();
   if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(employeeListFromUI)){
        for(EmployeeVO employee : employeeListFromUI){
            EmployeeDto employeeDto =  new EmployeeDto();
            employeeDto.setName(employee.getName());
            employeeDto.setAddressLine1(employee.getAddressLine1());
            if(employee.getAddressLine2()!=null && employee.getAddressLine2()!=""){
            employeeDto.setAddressLine2(employee.getAddressLine2());
            }
            employeeDto.setCity(employee.getCity());
            employeeDto.setState(employee.getState());
            employeeDto.setZip(employee.getZip());
            employees.add(employeeDto);
        }
    }
```

instead of this much of code using java 8 stream and forEach is it possible to write the above code in few lines.

Comment: Check out apache commons, [BeanUtils.copyProperties](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html)

Comment: @Miles I think that is using reflection, isn't it?

Comment: Yup, it is using reflection.

Comment: Can you create a `constructor` copy for `EmployeeDto` witch takes instance of `EmployeeVO` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could move this:

```
EmployeeDto employeeDto =  new EmployeeDto();
employeeDto.setName(employee.getName());
employeeDto.setAddressLine1(employee.getAddressLine1());
if(employee.getAddressLine2()!=null && employee.getAddressLine2()!=""){
   employeeDto.setAddressLine2(employee.getAddressLine2());
}
employeeDto.setCity(employee.getCity());
employeeDto.setState(employee.getState());
employeeDto.setZip(employee.getZip());
employees.add(employeeDto);
```

to a separate method, like :

```
private static EmployeeDto transform(EmployeeVO input) {
    // transform and return
}
```

And the use it in the form:

```
employeeListFromUI.stream()
                  .map(YourClass::tranform)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid this boiler plate code, you can use Dozer mapping API for transforming your `EmployeeVO` into `EmployeeDto` with very minimal code. You can look [here](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/usage.html) for Dozer example.

So, by with Dozer mapping, your code looks like:

**EmployeeDtoList class:**

```
public class EmployeeDtoList {

   private List<EmployeeDto> employees;

   //add getters and setters
}
```

**EmployeeVOList class:**

```
public class EmployeeVOList {

   private List<EmployeeVO> employees;

   //add getters and setters
}
```

**Converting beans:**

```
Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();

EmployeeVOList employeeVOList = 
    mapper.map(employeeListFromUI, EmployeeVOList.class);
```

You can use either dozer annotations (i.e., uses **`@Mapping` annotation**, look [here](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/annotations.html)) or xml to map each field inside `EmployeeDto` to `EmployeeVO`

**Note**: Dozer API
just avoids the boilerplae code i.e., **it does NOT specifically avoid any iterations** to copy the bean properties from one object into another.

Comment: I read somewhere that mapstruct is better than Dozer in terms of speed please refer http://mariusz.wyszomierski.pl/en/mapping-dozer-vs-mapstruct/

Answer (score 1):

Optional + flatMap + map:

```
Optional.ofNullable(employeeListFromUI)
    .flatMap(employeeList-> employeeList
    .stream.map(e -> mapToEmployeeDto(e))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[Example](https://medium.com/coding-with-clarity/understanding-the-optional-monad-in-java-8-e3000d85ffd2#.6lc70p4ou)

Comment: In this snippet is employeeList same as what i define employees empty arraylist or is it different  and what is mapToEmployeeDto(e) ?

Comment: no, `employeeList` it is your `employeeListFromUI` if it is not null,  `mapToEmployeeDto` it is method you need to write to copy properties from one object to another. Java 8 itself doesn't provide any new property setting approach. about optional and flatMap : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html